# How can I plot a symbolic function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
a=2;
b=9;  %the variance    
syms x 
i0=besseli(0,a*x/b);
fx=(x/b)*exp(-(x^2+a^2)/(2*b))*i0;
fun=matlabFunction(x*fx);
mean=quad(fun,0,282);
```

How can I plot `fx` and the integral of `fx`?

Answer (score 2):

To plot, you can do

```
xx = 0:.1:10;
fxx = matlabFunction(fx);
plot(xx, fxx(xx))
```

or

```
fxx = matlabFunction(fx);
fplot(fxx, [0 10])
```

And for the integral, one solution is:

```
fxx = matlabFunction(fx);
ifxx = @(x) integral(fxx,0,x);
fplot(ifxx, [0 10])
```

This is to get you going.
I hope there will better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using function "subs". That sound to be like this:

```
for i = Xstart:Xend
   y(i) = subs(f,x,i);
end

plot(Xstart:Xend,y)
```

I hope I could helped.

Answer (score 0):

There's a suite of "ez" ("easy") plot functions to handle this.  `ezplot`, `ezsurf`, `ezmesh`, and so on...

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/plot-functions-and-data.html for more information on the plotting functions supplied with the Symbolic Math Toolbox.